# Optimise PostGIS response size at lower zoom levels

Tags: node.js, postgresql, leaflet, maps, postgis

I have a large lines [data](https://cloud.fullstacklab.org/index.php/s/8EEWig6FGCNNiRn) which is being served by postgis server.
At first we used martin as a middleware , since martin is not customisable we stitched to a simple [nodejs-server](https://github.com/shanmukeshwar03/hallsell-postgis-api.git)

At higher zoom levels response size is reasonable , as zoom level decreases response size is growing higher and very costly request to postgres db.
I tried to use ST_Simplify which optimise the response size on the fly, but it didn't went well. Some articles say creating a simplified table of the original one for different zoom levels , how can I acheive it if my data is updating once a day ?

Sample example https://github.com/shanmukeshwar03/halsell-maps.git

Comment: If your data is updating, use SQL triggers.

Comment: Why does the zoomed-out data change every day?  How often does Paris, or the Grand Canyon, or Turkmenistan just get up and move?  And if the course of a river changes by 5 meters, does anyone who is zoomed out to be looking at the entire river care about that? I have nothing against re-computing it every day, but if that is a problem to do (performance reasons?), then maybe just don't do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: pg_tileserv is a good option. It's created and maintained by the lead developer of Postgis. Here is a blog post that describes some simple performance optimizations: https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/production-postgis-vector-tiles-caching

Comment: My data is a nightly build , it all about oil data which is going to update everyday
I'm expecting a solution which can merge features at lower zoom levels , since I don't need to show all the detailed features at such zoom level